# Mad Lib - Loops

Tags: python

> Write a program that takes a string and an integer as input, and outputs a sentence using the input values as shown in the example below. The program repeats until the input string is quit and disregards the integer input that follows.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> ```
> apples 5
> shoes 2
> quit 0
> ```
>
> the output is:
>
> ```
> Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.
> Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.
> ```

The code I have is:

```
user_input = input().split()
word = ""

while True:
    user_input = input().split()
    word = (user_input[0])
    if word == 'quit':
        break

    number = (user_input[1])
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(number, word))
```

With the provided input, I generate an output of "Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away."
How can I correct the code to generate an output, and continue to reloop and generate outputs until "quit" is identified?

Comment: remove first `input()`. You need `input()`only inside `while`-loop

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m not quite sure where you are talking about

Comment: see your code - you have two `user_input = input().split()` - first `user_input = input().split()` before `while` (in first line), second `user_input = input().split()` inside `while`. You have to remove first `user_input = input().split()`. That's all.

Comment: Ahh okay, that works now. Why would the first one cause the issue i was having ?

Comment: it seems obvious - first `input()` get first line - with `apple` - but later it makes nothing with this text and next code runs `while`-loop which runs second `input()` which get second line - with `shoes` and it displays this text.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
stop = "go"

while stop != "quit":
    user_input = input(" ").split(" ")
    stop = user_input[0]
    if user_input[0] == 'quit':
        break
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(user_input[1], user_input[0]))
```

Comment: remove the whitespace in first input bracket I am assuming this is a zybooks question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for me is as follows.

```
word = ""

while True:
    user_input = input().split()
    word = (user_input[0])
    if word == 'quit':
        break

    number = (user_input[1])
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(number, word))
    
    stop = "go"

while stop != "quit":
    stop = user_input[0]
    if user_input[0] == 'quit':
        break
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(user_input[1], user_input[0]))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).